# Are there any size limitations for C structures?

Tags: c, structure

Are there any size limitations for C structures?

Comment: Do you mean physical size in memory, or the number of members?

Comment: Physical size in memory.

Comment: If you have this consideration maybe using a struct is the wrong way?

Comment: yes, Physical size in memory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the C standard:

> **5.2.4.1 Translation limits**
>
> 1 The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least
>   one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the
>   following limits:
>
> ...
>   — 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
>   ... 
>   — 1023 members in a single structure or union
>   ... 
>   — 63 levels of nested structure or union definitions in a single
>   struct-declaration-list
>   ...
>   13) Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits
>   whenever possible.

Other than that, the upper bound is `SIZE_MAX` (maximum value for `size_t`).

Answer (score 7):

Since the `sizeof` operator yields a result of type `size_t`, the limit should be `SIZE_MAX`.

You can determine the value of `SIZE_MAX` like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  printf("%zu", SIZE_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

This is what the compiler should allow. What the runtime environment allows is another story.

Declaring a similarly sized object on the stack (locally) in practice will not work since the stack is probably much, much smaller than `SIZE_MAX`.

Having such an object globally might make the executable loader complain at program startup.

Comment: Can you tell what is the probable value of SIZE_MAX ? is it OS dependent ? i want to know the exact value.

Comment: I am genuinely curious about what size you want to use and why. Tell us?

Comment: At least in theory. In practice the limit is the memory in the computer, which is much smaller than `SIZE_MAX` on a modern 64-bit computer.

Comment: @Nemo Check the headerfile stdint.h, it should be there.

Comment: @Nemo: SIZE_MAX is compiler/architecture-dependent, meaning OS-dependent too, generally speaking. See its definition in stdint.h (or, if not there, possibly in limits.h) in your compiler's header files.

Answer (score 5):

**Empirical analysis**

In practice, implentations like GCC seem to only allow structs smaller than `size_t`, perhaps bound by `PTRDIFF_MAX`. See also: [What is the maximum size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c/31864574#31864574)

Using:

```
 for i in `seq 32`; do printf "typedef struct { S$i x; S$i y; } S$(($i+1));\n"; done
```

We make the program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { uint8_t i; } S0;
typedef struct { S0 x; S0 y; } S1;
typedef struct { S1 x; S1 y; } S2;
typedef struct { S2 x; S2 y; } S3;
typedef struct { S3 x; S3 y; } S4;
typedef struct { S4 x; S4 y; } S5;
typedef struct { S5 x; S5 y; } S6;
typedef struct { S6 x; S6 y; } S7;
typedef struct { S7 x; S7 y; } S8;
typedef struct { S8 x; S8 y; } S9;
typedef struct { S9 x; S9 y; } S10;
typedef struct { S10 x; S10 y; } S11;
typedef struct { S11 x; S11 y; } S12;
typedef struct { S12 x; S12 y; } S13;
typedef struct { S13 x; S13 y; } S14;
typedef struct { S14 x; S14 y; } S15;
typedef struct { S15 x; S15 y; } S16;
typedef struct { S16 x; S16 y; } S17;
typedef struct { S17 x; S17 y; } S18;
typedef struct { S18 x; S18 y; } S19;
typedef struct { S19 x; S19 y; } S20;
typedef struct { S20 x; S20 y; } S21;
typedef struct { S21 x; S21 y; } S22;
typedef struct { S22 x; S22 y; } S23;
typedef struct { S23 x; S23 y; } S24;
typedef struct { S24 x; S24 y; } S25;
typedef struct { S25 x; S25 y; } S26;
typedef struct { S26 x; S26 y; } S27;
typedef struct { S27 x; S27 y; } S28;
typedef struct { S28 x; S28 y; } S29;
typedef struct { S29 x; S29 y; } S30;
/*typedef struct { S30 x; S30 y; } S31;*/
S30 s;

int main(void) {
    printf("%jx\n", (uintmax_t)sizeof(s));
    return 0;
}
```

and then in Ubunbu 17.10:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2.0-6ubuntu1) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=c99 main.c
```

works. But if we uncomment `S31`, it fails with:

```
main.c:35:16: error: type ‘struct <anonymous>’ is too large
typedef struct { S30 x; S30 y; } S31;
```

So the maximum size is between 2^30 and (2^31 - 1).

Then we can convert `S30` to:

```
typedef struct { S29 x; S29 y; uint8_t a[(2lu << 29) - 1]; } S30;
```

and with that we determine that the maximum size is actually `2^31 - 1 == PTRDIFF_MAX` on this implementation.