# What is the size limit for a class?

Tags: c++, oop, class

I was wondering what the size limit for a class is. I did a simple test:

```
#define CLS(name,other) \
class name\
{\
public: \
name() {};\
   other a;\
   other b;\
   other c;\
   other d;\
   other e;\
   other f;\
   other g;\
   other h;\
   other i;\
   other j;\
   other k;\
};

class A{
   int k;
public:
   A(){};
};

CLS(B,A);
CLS(C,B);
CLS(D,C);
CLS(E,D);
CLS(F,E);
CLS(G,F);
CLS(H,G);
CLS(I,H);
CLS(J,I);
```

It fails to compile with

> "'J' : class is too large"

If I remove the final declaration - `CLS(J,I);`, it all compiles fine.

Is this a compiler-imposed restriction, or is it somewhere in the standard?

Comment: With the last define you reach about 10 GB (depending on padding) for the J class.

Comment: I was just declaring it, not actually using it. I bet declaring an array of some H classes would break the runtime :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724790/are-there-any-size-limitations-for-c-structures

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++11 this is Annex B. Implementations can impose limits, but they should be at least:

- Size of an object [262 144].
- Data members in a single class [16 384].
- Members declared in a single class [4 096].

The third one isn't directly relevant to the kind of construction you're using, I mention it just because it indicates that the second one is indeed the *total* members, presumably including those in bases and I'm not sure about members-of-members. But it's not just about the members listed in a single class definition.

Your implementation appears to have given up either 2^31 data members, or at size 2^32, since it accepts `I` but not `J`. It's fairly obviously reasonable for a compiler to refuse to consider classes with size greater than `SIZE_MAX`, even if the program happens not to instantiate it or use `sizeof` on the type. So even with the best possible effort on the part of the compiler I wouldn't ever expect this to work on a 32 bit implementation.

Note that "these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance", so a conforming implication can impose an arbitrary smaller limit even where it has sufficient resources to compile a program that uses larger numbers. There's no minimum limit for conformance.

There are various opportunities in the C++ standard for a conforming implementation to be useless due to ridiculously small resource limits, so there's no additional harm done if this is another one.

C++03 is more-or-less the same:

- Size of an object [262 144].
- Data members in a single class, structure, or union [16 384].
- Members declared in a single class [4 096].

Comment: @Steve Jessop.  Note that Annex B is not normative---the values given there are recommended minimums, and that in fact, I'd be very surprised if a 16 bit system supported a class with a size more than 65565.

Comment: @James: yes, I have noted that. Good point about 16 bit, you'd expect `SIZE_MAX` to be less than the recommended limit.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to mention another place in which class size limit is mentioned, which is in [section 1.2 of the Itanium C++ ABI draft](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#limits)

> Various representations specified by this ABI impose limitations on
>   conforming user programs. These include, for the 64-bit Itanium ABI:
>
> The offset of a non-virtual base subobject in the full object
>   containing it must be representable by a 56-bit signed integer (due to
>   RTTI implementation). This implies a practical limit of 2**55 bytes on
>   the size of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its compiler dependent. You can run your compiler in a preprocess only mode to see what the generated output is if you're curious. You might also want to look at template expansion rather than macros.

Comment: This was just a pure theoretical question, that's why I'm using macros. Why would I need templates? Also, if it's compiler specific, there must be some mention of a minimum limit in the standard. That's the kind of answer I was looking for.