# What is the maximum size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I understand that hardware will limit the amount of memory allocated during program execution. However, my question is **without regard to hardware.** Assuming that there was no limit to the amount of memory, would there be no limit to the array?

Comment: Actually software (OS) is the thing that will normally cause the memory limit seen by your C program.

Comment: Without a limit on memory, there is no limit on the pointer size. Without a limit on pointer size, all bets are off.

Comment: it would be limited by the size of the pointer (32 bit versus 64 bit)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no *fixed* limit to the size of an array in C.

The size of any single object, including of any array object, is limited by `SIZE_MAX`, the maximum value of type `size_t`, which is the result of the `sizeof` operator.  (It's not entirely clear whether the C standard permits objects larger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes, but in practice such objects are not supported; see footnote.)  Since `SIZE_MAX` is determined by the implementation, and cannot be modified by any program, that imposes an upper bound of `SIZE_MAX` bytes for any single object. (That's an upper bound, not a least upper bound; implementations may, and typically do, impose smaller limits.)

The width of the type `void*`, a generic pointer type, imposes an upper bound on the total size of all objects in an executing program (which may be larger than the maximum size of a single object).

The C standard imposes lower bounds, but not upper bounds, on these fixed sizes.  No conforming C implementation can support infinite-sized objects, but it can in principle support objects of any finite size.  Upper bounds are imposed by individual C implementations, by the environments in which they operate, and by physics, not by the language.

For example, a conforming implementation could have `SIZE_MAX` equal to 2<sup>1024</sup>-1, which means it could *in principle* have objects up to 179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137215 bytes.

Good luck finding hardware that actually supports such objects.

*Footnote*: There is no explicit rule that no object can be bigger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes.  You couldn't usefully apply the `sizeof` operator to such an object, but like any other operator, `sizeof` can overflow; that doesn't mean you couldn't perform operations on such an object.  But in practice, any sane implementation will make `size_t` big enough to represent the size of any object it supports.

Comment: Couldn't I use a arbitrary precision library to extend that max? I mean, theoretically speaking... :p

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: In principle, I suppose a compiler could use an arbitrary precision library to implement very wide integer types. But you can't do that as a programmer; actual integer types (with literals, operators, and so forth) are limited to what the compiler provides.

Comment: does the existence of [far pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) and the correspoing memory model change your answer in any way?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No. Far pointers are non-standard. Even if they were standard, I don't see how it would change my answer; far pointers are still fixed in size.

Comment: @KeithThompson: as I understand it 16-bit far pointers can address 20-bit space. I don't know but does it mean that there can be an object larger than "The width of the type `void*`"?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I've never used `far` pointers myself, but my understanding is that they include both the segment number and the offset within the segment. If a 16-bit pointer can access 20 bits worth of address space, there must be at least 4 bits of implicit information somewhere else, which as I understand it is exactly what `far` pointers *don't* do. In a conforming C implementation, a `void*` can uniquely address every byte of every object that currently exists.

Comment: "The size of any single object is limited by `SIZE_MAX`" contradicts the discussion in the footnote. I guess you mean that sentence should be interpreted as "In practice, the size of any single object is limited by `SIZE_MAX`", but I don't see any basis for that claim other than the footnote implication "It would not be sane".

Comment: @KeithThompson: I intended to init a large array in c, the following had "Segmentation fault" in 64 bit linux. In Java, I could have an array as large as 268435455 with no problem. Any comments about it?

#include <stdio.h>
//#define MAXSIZE 268435455
  #define MAXSIZE 10000000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("MAXSIZE = %lu\n", MAXSIZE);
    unsigned long data[MAXSIZE];
    printf("Done\n");
}

Comment: @caot: Your array is defined inside a function without the `static` keyword, so it has automatic storage duration. On most implementations, such objects are allocated on the stack. It's likely your system limits the size of the stack. Use `static`, or define it globally, or use `malloc()`.

Comment: @M.M: There's nothing in the standard that forbids objects bigger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes, but in practice any reasonable implementation that can support objects bigger than, say, 2**32 bytes will make `size_t` wider than 32 bits. An implementation that lets you define such large objects but doesn't bother to make `size_t` big enough to hold their size might be conforming, but it would be perverse.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You are right! Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Good luck finding hardware that actually supports such objects." Oh, so you are saying, SIZE_MAX should be enough for everybody, do you?

Comment: Some implementations, like gcc, only support objects of half the pointer width or smaller, i.e. PTRDIFF_MAX bytes.  This lets gcc implement pointer subtraction without keeping the carry-out from the integer `sub` of the pointers before scaling by the type width.  But [you can write a program where `malloc` succeeds for a size larger than that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c#comment85864410_31864574).  At least there's a warning when it's known at compile time.  You (unintentionally?) imply that objects of SIZE_MAX should be supported.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I didn't mention originally mention that implementations can impose smaller limits. I've updated my answer.

Comment: FWIW: MSVC has a much smaller limit than SIZE_MAX.  Consider error [C2148](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2148?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2148)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170): *total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes*.  Note that it doesn't matter whether you use arrays of bytes, ints, multidimensional arrays, what have you.  If sizeof(arr) > 0x7fffffff, the compiler will reject it (VS 2022).

Answer (score 13):

**C99 5.2.4.1 "Translation limits" minimal size**

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits: 13)
>
> - 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
>
> 13. Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.

This suggests that a conforming implementation could refuse to compile an object (which includes arrays) with more than `short` bytes.

**`PTRDIFF_MAX` also imposes some limits on array says**

The C99 standard *6.5.6 Additive operators* says:

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
> or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
> subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
> and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header.
> If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.

Which implies to me that arrays larger than `ptrdiff_t` are allowed in theory, but then you cannot take the difference of their addresses portabibly.

So perhaps for this reason, GCC just seems to limit you to `ptrdiff_t`. This is also mentioned at: [Why is the maximum size of an array "too large"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574890/why-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-too-large-in-gcc/42575849#42575849)

**Experiments**

Maybe what ultimately matters is whatever your compiler will accept, so here we go:

main.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

TYPE a[(NELEMS)];

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

sizes.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("PTRDIFF_MAX 0x%jx\n", (uintmax_t)PTRDIFF_MAX);
    printf("SIZE_MAX    0x%jx\n", (uintmax_t)SIZE_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

And then we try to compile with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o sizes.out sizes.c
./sizes.out
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out \
  -DNELEMS='((2lu << 62) - 1)' -DTYPE=uint8_t main.c
```

Results:

- PTRDIFF_MAX: 0x7fffffffffffffff = 2^63 - 1
- SIZE_MAX: 0xffffffffffffffff = 2^64 - 1
- `-DNELEMS='((2lu << 62) - 1)' -DTYPE=uint8_t`: compiles (== 2^63 - 1). Running it segfaults immediately on my mere 32 GB RAM system :-)
- `-DNELEMS='(2lu << 62)' -DTYPE=uint8_t`: compilation fails with:

  ```
  error: size of array ‘a’ is too large
  ```
- `-DNELEMS='(2lu << 62 - 1)' -DTYPE=uint16_t`: compilation fails with:

  ```
  error: size ‘18446744073709551614’ of array ‘a’ exceeds maximum object size ‘9223372036854775807’
  ```

  where `9223372036854775807 == 0x7fffffffffffffff`

So from this we understand that GCC imposes two limitations with different error messages:

- number of elements cannot exceed 2^63 (happens to == PTRDIFF_MAX)
- array size cannot exceed 2^63 (also happens to == PTRDIFF_MAX)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 amd64, GCC 9.3.0.

**See also**

- [Are there any size limitations for C structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724790/are-there-any-size-limitations-for-c-structures/49206497#49206497)
- [What is the correct type for array indexes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/type-for-array-index-in-c99)

Comment: gcc doesn't support dynamic arrays larger than half the pointer width either.  Note that pointer-subtraction results are scaled by the object size, so in theory a 3GiB array of `int` on an ILP32 target should work, and `end - start` should give `3 * 1024**3 / 4`, calculated *without* overflow, because the C standard says it's not UB if final result is representable.  But gcc emits code that does subtraction with pointer width and then arithmetic right-shifts that, losing the carry-out from the subtraction.  https://godbolt.org/g/NG6zZ6.

Comment: I tested with `-m32` and got `-536870896` (pointer subtraction) vs. `536870928` (manual).   Glibc `malloc` did succeed for an allocation of 2GiB + 16, on in 32-bit user-space on x86 (under a 64-bit kernel).  It failed for a 3GiB allocation, though.  Anyway, apparently this is "not a bug", because gcc considers PTRDIFF_MAX the max object size: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/02/22/memory-error-detection-using-gcc/.  `-Walloc-size-larger-than=PTRDIFF_MAX` is enabled by `-Wall`, and I got that warning while compiling my test program.

Comment: In fact there's already a (closed-invalid) gcc bug confirming that this is really how gcc works: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45779

Comment: Is that limit (`PTRDIFF_MAX`) the limit in number of elements, or in bytes?  As I see it, that's a limit in elements, but if elements are big enough, you could easily hit first the hard limit in bytes (`SIZE_MAX`).  That would be dangerous though, because functions that access that array through a `char *` could be problematic.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito my thinking is that you can ways typecast the pointer of the larger size to uint8_t, and then you would be able to reach differences larger than PTRDIFF_MAX. Just a heuristic of why GCC seems to do what it does though. I improved the experiments a bit now.

Comment: @alx: It's in bytes.  The reason is that pointer-subtraction is required to be accurate when it doesn't overflow the final value even if the byte distance wouldn't fit (if the pointers had been cast to `char*` before subtracting). Setting an implementation limit means GCC can implement `end - start` for wider types as raw integer subtraction of the pointers, and division by `sizeof(T)` (using a shift or multiplicative inverse of course).  If that had to give accurate results even for pointers 2.1 GiB apart on a 32-bit system, it would need ext prec. or rotate the carry flag in to divide by 2.

Answer (score 5):

Without regard for memory, the maximum size of an array is limited by the type of integer used to index the array.

Comment: `When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
result has the type of the pointer operand` (C11 n1570, section 6.5.6 Additive operators).  So using an integer type wider than a pointer isn't allowed to give you access to more memory than you could access otherwise.  (Recall that `arr[idx]` is exactly equivalent to `*((arr) + (idx))`, and that's in fact how the C standard defines the `[]` array subscript operator.)  Anyway, that's a limit that all C implementations share, but in practice implementations have smaller limits, like PTRDIFF_MAX for gcc.

Answer (score 5):

A 64-bit machine could theoretically address a maximum of 2^64 bytes of memory.

Comment: Good luck putting that amount of memory into a computer. Even with Moore's law that's a long time coming.

Comment: I could imagine it happening within my lifetime though.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. I have accessed 22-bits of address space on a 16-bit machine. There is no reason a “64-bit machine,” which has no firm definition, is restricted to 64 bits of address space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you can theoretically combine any amount of unitary information type in order to access a higher magnitude of adresses. But that is not the point. A pointer, as is defined, is 64 bits, and therefore adresses 2^64 addresses of memory. You can't make enough combinations with 16 bits and address every single cell of memory in a 22 bit machine.

Comment: @AntónioOliveira: This answer does not say a pointer defined to be 64 bits can address a maximum of 2^64 addresses, which would be true (except of course for the null pointer value). It says a 64-bit machine can address a maximum of 2^64 addresses, which is false. The term “64-bit machine“ does not have a single technical definition. Generally, it can mean the general processor registers are 64 bits wide, or the bus is 64 bits wide, or instructions “mostly” operate on 64-bit-wide data, and so on…

Comment: … It does not mean the machine cannot use a variety of addressing techniques, such as using two registers (like segment and offset) to address memory. “64-bit machine” does not mean the pointers on the machine are 64 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil by that definition, no single data type structure is defined on a 64 bit machine, which is counter productive. As I included in my answer, you can join any unit of information and make it possible to address any quantity of information. But we live in the real world, and fantasy is often not an option. So for example in c, the maximum size for a pointer is 8 bytes, and since we're being practical, that is the limit that you should even need for the next 100-1000 years, but if you need to address more than 16 exabytes of memory, guess its a you problem ;).

Comment: @AntónioOliveira: As a matter of fact, no C data type is defined on a 64-bit machine or any other machine. Per the C standard, the types are defined by the C implementation, not by the target machine. Re “But we live in the real world”: As I noted in my first comment, I have accessed 22 bits of address space on a 16-bit machine in the real world. This is a matter of fact. Quite possibly, you are accustomed to using only architectures with simple flat address spaces. But others exist, and the C standard is designed to accommodate them.

Comment: @AntónioOliveira: Re “So for example in c, the maximum size for a pointer is 8 bytes”: The C standard imposes no such limit, and a C implementation might want to use larger pointers for reasons other than simply increasing the number of addressable bytes, such as adding debugging information or a hash for pointer authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the biggest theoretical array would be the max value of "unsigned long" (or whatever the biggest integer number the latest standard / your compiler supports)

Comment: Not if that's wider than a pointer.  (e.g. `long long` on an implementation with 32-bit pointers).

Answer (score 2):

The size of the pointer will limit the memory you are able to access. Even if the hardware offers support for unlimited memory, if the largest datatype you are able to use is 64 bit, you'll only be able to access 2^64 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to determine the maximum size for an array. This question seems to ask the same, so I want to share my findings.

Initially, C does not provide any function to determine the maximum number of elements allocable in an array in compilation time. This is because it will depend of the memory of available in the machine where it will be executed.

On the other hand, I have found, that memory allocation functions (`calloc()` and `malloc()`) enable to allocate larger arrays. Moreover, these functions allows you to handle runtime memory allocation errors.

Hope that helps.