# How to read and write class with dynamic array member from/to binary file C++

Tags: c++

**The problem:** I'm having a problem with reading and writing files in binary mode using **C++ stl only**. What I have in my class are 2 integer member to tell me the matrix's size and the actual matrix itself. The matrix is dynamic though which I think is the main reason why non of my read request is correct. So my question is how do I read/write for class with dynamic arrays member.

**What I've tried:** reading in the size of the matrix before hands and then allocate memory for the matrix array. But for some reason my debugger just keeps saying it's segmentation fault although I have made some room for it. I've even tried to make two class with the same member values, still nothing

```
class MaTrix{
private :
    int row, column;
    float ** maTrix_arr;
}
void outFile(){
    ofstream of("matrix.inp", ios::binary | ios::app) ;
    of.write(reinterperted_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)) ;
}
void inFile(){
    ifstream ifs("matrix.inp", ios::binary | ios::app) ; // if I don't use app it will delete my file for some reason
    // I do some more allocation here to make sure the Matrix is of suitable size
    // Long code short I tried to get the two integers row and column out and it works as intended
    // Then I allocate some memory for this->maTrix_arr, also making sure I reset the file pointer
    ifs.read(reinterperted_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this)) ;
}
};
```

Comment: You're attempting to write and read *pointers* (it seems). A pointer is local to the currently running process, it will not be valid in any other process, not even a process running the same program.

Comment: As for *one* possible way to solve the problem, just write and read *text*. Write each "row" of the matrix as a separate line in the file. That way it's actually very easy to read and write the data. And if you use `std::vector` instead, then it becomes even easier.

Comment: Write the *data* that is represented by the matrix, not the pointers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this

Comment: I wanted to read everything in one go, that's why I've used binary mode, other than that I thought this pointer here  meant that the data is being writen/read, not the pointer itself

Comment: You will find plenty of "elaboration" in your C++ book, specifically the chapters that explains what pointers are, and how to use them. In the meantime, try to wrap your brain around something very simple: `sizeof()` is a compile-time constant. The `sizeof` of your object is always the same, where your matrix has just one or two values, or several trillion. It's the size of two integers, and a pointer. On modern 64 bit platforms, your `sizeof()` will always evaluate to 24. If you doubt that, just `std::cout << sizeof(*this)`. Think about it.

Comment: I still need to allocate more memory for the actual array before reading it right ?

Comment: The thing is even when I have or have not allocate memory for the array, it would still get segmentation fault

Comment: Oh boy nvm I just realized it now, I'm so dumb

Comment: How is your file formatted?

Comment: @TraiViệtNam To add to SamV's comment, if you need to be further convinced, open the file you saved in a text editor.  Does what you see make any sense?  It won't make sense.  So how are you going to turn that gibberish you see into real data?  Sorry, but no amount of magic will turn that file back into the original data.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is some [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) library. And you probably want to use [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), so you would serialize some `std::vector<double>` for a vector, and you would define your own `template matrix<typename ElementType>` (or better yet find one, perhaps in [Boost](https://boost.org/), which fits your needs). You certainly need to define the [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) for your matrixes (so the collection of all the operations on them). BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410503/841108) answer (for C) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943172/841108) one could inspire you.

You obviously should not write raw pointers in a file, because they make sense only for your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). Even if you run the same program in the same state (e.g. same matrixes) in two different processes, they would use different pointer addresses (e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). You want to write (and later read) the *contents* of your matrixes.

You might be interested in existing serialization libraries such as [s11n](http://www.s11n.net/), or at least in neutral binary formats such as [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). You probably should care about [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (e.g. if reading on a Sparc or ARM computer a binary file written on x86).

You could decide to serialize in some textual format (or [text-based protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol)), such as [JSON](https://json.org/) (or YAML, etc...). This is more friendly to developers (and for debugging). You can find a lot of JSON related libraries for C++, e.g. [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

If you are not allowed to use external libraries, you could reinvent and *document* (perhaps in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation) your textual serialization format (inspired by JSON, or by [S-exprs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)) and easily implement it (using usual [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, such as [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)).

If you are required to use a binary format, you need to specify it (again EBNF notation should help) and implement it (again, it is a parsing problem for the decoding; encoding is usually much simpler).

Very probably, you want to encode (and decode) each matrix element one by one. That is not a big deal, once your abstract data type has the operations to fetch (and perhaps to change) the value of some individual matrix element.

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The thing is, I can't use anything outside of stl

Comment: That constraint should go into your question.

Comment: I have it inside my question, maybe it wasn't obvious enough