# Why is there a maximum limit for size of arrays in java?

Tags: java, stack, heap-memory

I got to find from 
[Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)
that there is a maximum limit for array size .

May be with the intention that it might deplete heap space . Yes,  I agree with the point .

I cannot understand the following :

1. But why to have this limit for every single array ?
2. what if I have a number of arrays of such large size ?
3. why not throw an exception when some threshhold of heap space  is reached overall(total consumption) , instead of having upperbound for each array ?

Note :

1. In Python, they have this limit [How Big can a Python Array Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855191/1065197)
2. In C , there seems like no limit (except the hardware used) [The maximum size of an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9386979/1065197)

Comment: Nothing to do with heap space.  All to do with using a 32-bit integer for addressing.

Comment: And that the array space must be contiguous.  It may be relatively easy to allocate a 2GB array when the JVM starts up, but in a long-running application with a fragmented heap (depending on your GC implementation) it may be nearly impossible.

Comment: But why ? had the array been designed with index being a still more larger range this would have been possible ? may I know why the silly index the limiting factor for such a feature . to be practical its like saying "because the person's name has only six characters he can study only till 6th standard "from textbooksonline.tn.nic.in/Books/11/Std11-CompSci-EM-2.pdf page 257 I am getting a sense that only address matters and index is just used to calculate next address from starting address . so why is this index given so much importance and serves as a limiting factor for size of array. –

Comment: I found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: Fun corollary: all of `ArrayList`'s operations are actually O(1), even though we think of them as O(N). For instance, `contains(Object)` is O(1) because I can come up with a constant (2^31-1) which is a JLS-enforced ceiling for how many steps it'll take (with some constant multiplier). :)  (But don't say it's O(N) on any test or in an interview!)

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in java are indexed by int values. So even if you have infinte memory, the max no. of elements an array can hold is 2^31-1 (Please correct me if I am wrong with the number... but you get the idea).

However, your memory will limit you on how many such large arrays you can keep in your heap...

Answer (score 3):

The `length` of an array is an `int`, so you can't allow arrays with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements without breaking `length`. Breaking `length` would be huge; it would require source changes and recompilation all over the place.

Given that you already have a length cap mandated by the `length` field, there's not a huge difference between a cap of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`.

Comment: Oh Thanks.But why ? had the array been designed with index being a still more larger range this would have been possible ? may I know why the silly index the limiting factor for such a feature . to be practical its like saying "because the person's name has only six characters he can study only till 6th standard ".

Comment: from http://www.textbooksonline.tn.nic.in/Books/11/Std11-CompSci-EM-2.pdf page 257 I am getting a sense that only address matters and index is just used to calculate next address from starting address . so why is this index given so much importance .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: Making the length a long would require unwieldy casts and two extra, generally-unused bytes for all arrays.

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam may I ask you why would you use an array with 2147483647 elements inside it? Do you have such real world use case or is it pure curiosity?

Comment: No I was reading datastructures and slowly started to go inside and  explore things and I found this limiting factor and was puzzled .Could not think of a reason , so raised it here .Did you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c .

Comment: @user2357112 : why is the index range going to create unused bytes ? it is just for calculation and implementation pupose right . it is finally only the starting address that is stored (I have quoted a reference in comment 2 a book). They have index to deduce memory address of some other element in array as starting_address + (size of each element)*index

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam no, but it is good to know for curiosity purposes. In real world applications, you would not use such enormous arrays, I guess that was the motivation for James Gosling to design arrays in Java to have at most an `int` maximum value as the maximum length value for arrays.

Comment: Ya this answer sounds meaningful . It was just a design decision and because of its lack of usefulness it was designed this way.

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: If you make the length a long, you need to store an 8-byte long instead of a 4-byte int. You're not just storing the array's starting address (in fact, the array's address isn't part of the array at all; it's the cost of the reference to the array).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say if you have a array

```
String[] array = new String[22L];
```

Error message in eclipse

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int
```

Clearly tells that the size of array takes int for length which is limited by ** max int value which is limited by 32-bits**

Comment: Try adding an L at the end.

Comment: You can not do that. Because arrays take int as their size. in that case the error message eclipse will show is Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

Comment: Then the second error message is the proper explanation for this reason.

Comment: Try your self you cannot create a array  String[] array = new String[1L]; if that explains :)

Comment: Again: your second explanation (in comments) is the right one. The explanation in your current post **it is not**.

Comment: By the way, your error message refers to literal integers, not to the size of the array nor the type of the size of the array (so your explanation does not explain why the array takes `int` as its size).

Comment: And that error message is clear enough that max size of arrays is limited by max int value. Because arrays dont take long etc as their size. Strange you still insist.  I am not even talking about type of array.

Comment: It is not. That error message is for trying to store a value bigger than an int inside an int.