# Why is the maximum size of an array "too large"?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, size-t, stdint

I'm under the same impression as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387041/584518), that `size_t` is always guaranteed by the standard to be large enough to hold the largest possible type of a given system.

However, this code fails to compile on gcc/Mingw:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef uint8_t array_t [SIZE_MAX];
```

> error: size of array 'array_t' is too large

Am I misunderstanding something in the standard here? Is `size_t` allowed to be too large for a given implementation?  Or is this another bug in Mingw?

---

EDIT: further research shows that

```
typedef uint8_t array_t [SIZE_MAX/2];   // does compile
typedef uint8_t array_t [SIZE_MAX/2+1]; // does not compile
```

Which happens to be the same as

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef uint8_t array_t [LLONG_MAX];           // does compile
typedef uint8_t array_t [LLONG_MAX+(size_t)1]; // does not compile
```

So I'm now inclined to believe that this is a bug in Mingw, because setting the maximum allowed size based on a signed integer type doesn't make any sense.

Comment: An array of size `SIZE_MAX` probably consumes all of memory.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Then why did they pick a number which is too large for the given implementation?

Comment: I tried it and oddly, `typedef uint8_t array_t [SIZE_MAX/2];` compiles fine

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No... arrays subscripts have to be of type `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` is the maximum value of such a variable. You can't declare arrays with zero or negative length.

Comment: @samgak But it turns out that `typedef uint8_t array_t [SIZE_MAX/2+1];` does not compile, see edit above. Seems to be a Mingw bug as far as I can tell.

Comment: According to GCC [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/96afa092673def81e434b7d92ed47effb972cb2b/gcc/c/c-decl.c#L6108) the limit is enforced by signed counterpart of `sizetype` (`INT_MAX` in comment is misleading). `index` is assigned with `c_common_signed_type (sizetype);` at line 5933. This probably explains "half-range" issue.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Looks like you found the bug then? Or is there some rationale behind picking a signed type? Otherwise you should post this as the answer to the question and then somebody can file a bug report.

Comment: @Lundin: I haven't found any comments, why they are taking signed type, so it may be a bug. Edit: I think that 2501 is right and it is due to `ptrdiff_t` type, which is signed.

Comment: Current hardware use 48 bits of virtual address space. If you don't have any 48 bit integer types, you would have to use a 64 bit `size_t`.

Comment: You'll notice that nothing in the standard implies that the compiler must allow objects of any size up to `SIZE_MAX`. It only implies that the compiler must not allow objects larger than `SIZE_MAX`. That's true even if you don't actually create the object, since `sizeof` can be applied to types too.

Comment: Re. the first paragraph, `size_t` holds integer values, not types.

Comment: A more "according to standards" version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: I like @AnT explaination better than the chosen one, but ultimately I wonder if it's not better to dupe close this question and merge that content into the other question that is linked. You are **certainly** right to ask this, but it requires only a minor extension on the other question. It seems what StackOverflows needs is one canonical answer on size_t/ptrdiff_t/intptr_t, and all these other questions closed.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The limit SIZE_MAX / 2 comes from the definitions of size_t and ptrdiff_t on your implementation, which choose that the types ptrdiff_t and size_t have the same width.

C Standard mandates<sup>1</sup>  that type size_t is unsigned and type ptrdiff_t is signed.

The result of difference between two pointers, will always<sup>2</sup> have the type ptrdiff_t. This means that, on your implementation, the size of the object must be limited to 
PTRDIFF_MAX, otherwise a valid difference of two pointers could not be represented in type ptrdiff_t, leading to undefined behavior.

Thus the value SIZE_MAX / 2 equals the value PTRDIFF_MAX. If the implementation choose to have the maximum object size be SIZE_MAX, then the width of the type ptrdiff_t would have to be increased. But it is much easier to limit the maximum size of the object to SIZE_MAX / 2, then it is to have the type ptrdiff_t have a greater or equal positive range than that of type size_t.

Standard offers these<sup>3</sup>  comments<sup>4</sup> on the topic.

---

(Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x)

<sup>1</sup> (7.19 Common definitions  2)
The types are
ptrdiff_t
which is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers;
size_t
which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

<sup>2</sup> (6.5.6 Additive operators 9)
When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
and its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the  header.
If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.

<sup>3</sup> (K.3.4 Integer types  3)
Extremely large object sizes are frequently a sign that an object’s size was calculated
incorrectly. For example, negative numbers appear as very large positive numbers when
converted to an unsigned type like size_t. Also, some implementations do not support
objects as large as the maximum value that can be represented by type size_t.

<sup>4</sup> (K.3.4 Integer types  4)
For those reasons, it is sometimes beneficial to restrict the range of object sizes to detect
programming errors. For implementations targeting machines with large address spaces,
it is recommended that RSIZE_MAX be defined as the smaller of the size of the largest
object supported or (SIZE_MAX >> 1), even if this limit is smaller than the size of
some legitimate, but very large, objects. Implementations targeting machines with small
address spaces may wish to define RSIZE_MAX as SIZE_MAX, which means that there is no object size that is considered a runtime-constraint violation.

Comment: This makes sense. So it is rather a defect in the C standard then? Meaning that `SIZE_MAX` can never be used in meaningful ways, but `size_t` should instead rather be using `PTRDIFF_MAX`?

Comment: @Lundin It is not a defect because SIZE_MAX doesn't represent the value of the maximum allowable size of an object. Even using PTRDIFF_MAX as the limit is not correct, because it could theoretically be larger than SIZE_MAX. I think the correct value is `min(SIZE_MAX,PTRDIFF_MAX)`.

Comment: gcc could however have chosen to do `#define SIZE_MAX PTRDIFF_MAX`. It would have made it consistent with the C standard without the need of inventing some huge ptrdiff_t.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't think that would be allowed since the C standard defines `SIZE_MAX` as the "limit of `size_t`" (C99 Section 7.20.3).

Comment: @Lundin: You seem to be under a misapprehension of the purpose of `SIZE_MAX`.  It is *not* intended to be "the maximum possible size of an object" at all.  It is intended to be "the maximum possible value of an integer of type `size_t`."  While we do use `size_t` to measure the sizes of objects, there is no requirement that the implementation actually permit the creation of such enormous objects.  To be clear, `SIZE_MAX / 2` is still an absurdly huge number on a 64-bit system; no sane programmer will ever want to create an array that big even as a static global variable.

Comment: The standard allows an implementation  to offer objects greater than PTRDIFF_MAX;  the only drawback is that subtracting two pointers far enough apart would cause undefined behaviour. (Which is a pretty big drawback and explains why they choose not to do that).

Answer (score 23):

The of range `size_t` is guaranteed to be sufficient to store the size of the largest object supported by the implementation. The reverse is not true: you are not guaranteed to be able to create an object whose size fills the entire range of `size_t`.

Under such circumstances the question is: what does `SIZE_MAX` stand for? The largest supported object size? Or the largest value representable in `size_t`? The answer is: it is the latter, i.e. `SIZE_MAX` is `(size_t) -1`. You are not guaranteed to be able to create objects `SIZE_MAX` bytes large.

The reason behind that is that in addition to `size_t`, implementations must also provide `ptrdiff_t`, which is intended (but not guaranteed) to store the difference between two pointers pointing into the same array object. Since type `ptrdiff_t` is signed, the implementations are faced with the following choices:

1. Allow array objects of size `SIZE_MAX` and make `ptrdiff_t` *wider* than `size_t`. It has to be wider by at least one bit. Such `ptrdiff_t` can accommodate any difference between two pointers pointing into an array of size `SIZE_MAX` or smaller.
2. Allow array objects of size `SIZE_MAX` and use `ptrdiff_t` of *the same width* as `size_t`. Accept the fact that pointer subtraction can *overflow* and cause undefined behavior, if the pointers are farther than `SIZE_MAX / 2` elements apart. The language specification does not prohibit this approach.
3. Use `ptrdiff_t` of the same width as `size_t` and *restrict* the maximum array object size by `SIZE_MAX / 2`. Such `ptrdiff_t` can accommodate any difference between two pointers pointing into an array of size `SIZE_MAX / 2` or smaller.

You are simply dealing with an implementation that decided to follow the third approach.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't attempt to create any array objects though, it only makes a typedef. So is it non-conforming for the implementation to reject the typedef?

Comment: I really think this is close to a canonical answer (for all this ptrdiff/size/intptr stuff) and would urge you to merge you other answer into this one, outline the _MAX and _MIN constants for each type in question before you get into explaining them (because references make it easier) and bring the details of the others answers into this one. Good job!

Comment: Actually having your answer and the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c/9387041#9387041 I almost feel like it's a diservice to allow the other one to remain open. Perhaps you could migrate your answer to that question and just dupe-close this entirely.

Comment: Not sure if you want an update for more symmetry in your very awesome breakdown, feel free to grab this through makes it a lot easier to process that. (imho) https://gist.github.com/EvanCarroll/121dfb870fd3da0dc52ba4e7edefe3ee

Comment:  nailed it, all that's left is to point out how implementations of any programming language are technically limited and yet intended to be somewhat functionally useful... We could probably hack our OS up to give us a 4GB stack, but that'd be mostly wasted and so the decision was to settle with somewhere around 1-4MB callstack space (which is where this allocation will likely end up, unless allocated), and just because it compiles that doesn't mean it functions usefully...

Comment: Also, I feel like waking up to the classical definition of _object_ (which is a necessary storage area for change of state, and doesn't necessarily require being _addressable_ or iterable using C-style pointer arithmetic)... We can `mmap` an array against an entire disk and, assuming 32-bit `size_t`, we simply won't be able to access beyond 2-4GB. However, if we stick to `read` and `write` calls upon a special block device, we can access anywhere on the device, we could theoretically have an infinitely long tape. In practice, this will be slower, so our programs should meet somewhere between.

Answer (score 5):

It looks very much like implementation-specific behaviour.

I'm running here Mac OS, and with gcc 6.3.0 the biggest size I can compile your definition with is `SIZE_MAX/2`; with `SIZE_MAX/2 + 1` it does not compile anymore.

On the other side, witch clang 4.0.0 the biggest one is `SIZE_MAX/8`, and `SIZE_MAX/8 + 1` breaks.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX/8+1` Interesting. what is the error message there? Can you successfully malloc `SIZE_MAX/8+1`?

Comment: Error message is very much the same: `error: array is too large (2305843009213693952 elements)`

Comment: `clang 4.0.0` What is the value RSIZE_MAX and what is the value of PTRDIFF_MAX?

Comment: `SIZE_MAX: 18446744073709551615 RSIZE_MAX: 9223372036854775807 PTRDIFF_MAX: 9223372036854775807`

Comment: Indeed. No, I cannot malloc even `SIZE_MAX/128/1024`: blah-blah, `set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`. `SIZE_MAX/256/1024` mallocs fine. +1/-1 to those don't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just reasoning from scratch, `size_t` is a type that can hold the size of any object. The size of any object is limited by the width of the address bus (ignoring multiplexing and systems that can handle eg 32 and 64 bit code, call that "code width"). Anologous to `MAX_INT` which is the largest integer value, `SIZE_MAX` is the largest value of `size_t`. Thus, an object of size `SIZE_MAX` is all addressable memory. It s reasonable that an implementation flags that as an error, however, I agree that it is an error only in a case where an actual object is allocated, be it on the stack or in global memory. (A call to `malloc` for that amount will fail anyway)