# malloc'ing 1TB of memory doesn't fail?

Tags: c, malloc

```
//gcc 5.4.0

#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Try to reserve 1 TB of memory
    int *arr = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    // Unfortunately most systems will actually allow this (swapping etc.)
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Was not able to reserve memory!\n");
    }
    printf("Everything is ok\n");

    return 0;
}
```

compiler options: `-Wall -std=c99  -o a.out source_file.c`

The output ("Everything is ok") is what confuses me. I obviously don't have 1TB of memory - and according to the C-Reference, malloc should return NULL if, and only if(!) something goes wrong.

This is clearly not happening here. Can somebody wiser explain?

Comment: You might want to free that memory after printf.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate

Comment: Hint: the result of that multiplication expression on your platform is nowhere *near* 1TB.

Comment: I vote for reopening the question, because OP does not try to allocate too much memory, he passes `0` to `malloc`: http://ideone.com/Lz6s75

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you sure? On my calculator 1024*1024*1024*1024 = 1099511627776 bytes, which sure looks like somewhere near 1TB

Comment: @Neil `1024` is an `int`, so the result of `1024 * 1024 * 1024` is also an `int`, which does not fit. `1073741824` modulo `4294967296` is `0`.

Comment: @Neil Sure. Mine too. But what does it evaluate to in the posted C code, particularly when compiled as a 32bit process or using 32bit `int`?

Comment: "I obviously don't have 1TB of memory" - Why is that obvious? And what is `SIZE_MAX` on your system?

Comment: @mch: Without more information this is not guaranteed. It depends on `SIZE_MAX` on the platform. But the calculation most likely invokes undefined behaviour due to `int` overflow.

Comment: Nevertheless, @Olaf, mch's explanation is certainly *plausible*.  On many common systems, although C declares the effect of evaluating the OP's multiplication expression to be undefined, the probability of that UB manifesting as mch describes is near unity.

Comment: @Olaf, `2**40` modulo `2**32` is 0, not 256.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Stupid me! You are right, of course! I should not correct others if I have my mind elsewhere :-)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Just ftr: I changed the wrong paragraph in my answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

> 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024

These are integer constants of type `int`. When multiplied together, the operations will get carried out on type `int`. The result will be of type `int`.

Most likely an `int` cannot hold a value larger than 2^32 / 2 -1 = `2.14*10^9` on your system.

Meaning that you overflow a signed int and invoke undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including malloc allocating some random chunk of data.

Comment: He does not convert it to int and malloc accept size_t which is 64 bit in a 64 bit system.

Comment: @LiranFunaro The type `malloc()` accepts is irrelevant.  The `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` occurs before `malloc()` is called.  That multiplication occurs using `int` math - which overflows on 32-bit `int` machines.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40633059/2410359).

Comment: But it will happen in compile time, not run time

Comment: @LiranFunaro With `void *malloc(size_t size);`, at run time or compile time, the type of `size_t size`, make _no difference_. `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` overflows 32-bit `int` math.  Does your compiler give a warning like "warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]" with `int *arr = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);`?  The conversion to `size_t` occurs _after_ the product is calculated.  By then it is too late.

Comment: Let's stop this argument. I'll check this when I'll get home. If I'm wrong I'll eat my hat and up vote.

Comment: @Olaf I don't have a picture, but if you'll edit I'll be able to upvote. "warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]"

Comment: @LiranFunaro: WHile he compiler is correct, arguing with a tool warning or not is a bad idea. The correct way is arguing with the standard for a standardised language like C (or C++ which has the same behaviour btw.). Next time please get familiar with the standard _first_; spares us a lot of time and anger (yes, It makes me upset being downvoted unjustified - it is not about the `-2` reps).

Comment: @Olaf The OP didn't mention any warning. I assumed he didn't have any.

Comment: @LiranFunaro: Read my comment carefully again! I explicitly stated you should argume by the standard, not a compiler. There is not requirement for a diagnostic! TRhat's what undefined behaviour implies.

Answer (score 2):

> according to the C-Reference, malloc should return NULL if, and only if(!) something goes wrong.

This is incorrect.

`malloc()` returns `NULL` under 2 conditions:

1. A *null pointer* if the memory could not be allocated.
2. On an allocation of 0, it is implementation defined if `malloc()` returns `NULL` or a non-`NULL` pointer (which can not be de-referenced).

OP's `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` overflows 32-bit `int` math that is *undefined behavior* or UB.  [@WhozCraig hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982699/mallocing-1tb-of-memory-doesnt-fail/43984596#comment74994713_43982699). A typical result is a truncated product which would be 0. OP's system is then returning a non-`NULL` pointer for a *zero byte allocation* as "Was not able to reserve memory!\n" was not printed.

If OP's platform uses a rare 64-bit `int`, the true allocation of memory may be [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359).

---

OP's is also missing out on the helpful advice of the compiler.  Increase warning options.  Certain the below will report a warning.

```
// -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99  -o a.out source_file.c

int *arr = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
// warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
```

---

Be sure the type of expression's math meets/exceeds the type of the target.  [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983174/2410359) and  [reasons not to use 100 * 1000 * 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

```
int *arr = malloc((size_t) 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `malloc(3)` manpage:

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy. This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee that the memory really is available.

This, of course, assumes you're on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have 1TB physical memory, but most OSs support virtual memory, backed by disk space.
When malloc asks for memory the system allocates virtual memory. A part of it will be real memory the rest will be most probably a file on your HD.

Answer (score -2):

`1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` most likely invokes undefined behaviour:
`1024` is a `int` constant. Operations are done with the "largest" type of both operands, but at least `int`. Both operands are `int`, so the multiplication types are `int * int -> int`. The same for the following multiplications. I.e. the final result is `int`. On typical systems `int` is not more than 32 bits. **The type of the parameter is irrelevant for the expression**.

The result of the multiplication overflows an `int` (unless it is more than 41 bits), which invokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen (often, but not guaranteed: the result is truncated, yielding `0`).

To avoid this, you should use `(size_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 *1024`. This will (according to conversion rules) will perform the calculations  with whichever standard type `size_t` has on your system.

Beforehand use a static assertion to ensure `size_t` can represent the result:

```
_Static_assert(SIZE_MAX >= 1024ULL * 1024 * 1024 *1024, "size_t is too small");`
```

Without this the multiplication would be truncated on a too small `size_t` (rules are different for signed and unsigned integers!) and you end up passing `0`.

According to the standard `malloc(0)` [is implementation defined either `NULL` or a pointer which must not be used to access an object](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1).

Keeping all this in mind, your code might return a non-null pointer, which must not be used for accesses. But as you just test it, it is fine, but useless.

Comment: It would probably be wiser to use `uint64_t` instead. `size_t` is not necessarily reliable, as I found out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574890/why-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-too-large).

Comment: @Lundin: `malloc` takes a `size_t` parameter, `uint64_t` might be too large already, so it _is_ the correct type. That's why the static assertion beforehand using a type guaranteed to be large enough.  Static allocation is somewhat more problematic. These limits are defined by the implementation limits in [5.2.4.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1p1); `malloc` should return `NULL` if the parameter value is beyond what it can even handle (that's a different matter from what is available for allocation).

Comment: He does not convert it to int and malloc accept size_t which is 64 bit in a 64 bit system.

Comment: @LiranFunaro - `1024 * 1024 ...` is **already** an `int` - no conversion is required to make it so.

Comment: @LiranFunaro: `1024` is guaranteed to fit into an `int` thus is has type `int`! C does **not** convert experssion operands to the target type, but according to the standard conversion rules as defined for each **operator**. These don't automatically convert any further than `int`, resp. the type of the largest operand. I request you to remove the downvote, as it is completely unjustified.

Comment: But the multiply will happen in compile time, which does convert the type.

Comment: @LiranFunaro: Please read the standard. **It will not**! And there is no difference **when** it is processed. The standard does not even guarantee when the expression is evaluated; that is an implementation detail; in fact it is unspecified, i.e. the implemntation can do what it wants even for the same expression in different places! As a sidenote: a language which made a difference here would be near unusable. But fee free to provide a reference to the standard if you still think different. Until then: The downvote ...

Comment: @LiranFunaro: An every-day example: if you have to identical buckets of water, each 3/4 full. Fill the water from both buckets into an identical third. Now you fill this bucket into a bathtub. Does that mean you have 1.5 buckets full of water in the tub?

Comment: The question was for this particular case (gcc 5.2). Not the standard.

Comment: @LiranFunaro, do not confuse the evaluation of an integer constant expression to obtain a C-language value with the evaluation of an integer expression by the preprocessor in a conditional compilation directive.  The latter is performed in the largest integer type available.  The former, which is what applies here, is performed according to the same rules as would apply to runtime evaluation.  In particular, the constant `1024` has type `int`, and the product of any two `int`s also has type `int`.

Comment: @LiranFunaro: 1) The question is tagged C, which implies standard. 2) gcc **does** implement the C standard. 3) There are four experienced users (not counting myself) telling you are wrong. How about doing research before discussing from a lost position?

Comment: @LiranFunaro, if you are arguing that GCC 5.2 deviates from the standard in this regard, then you would do well to present some documentation of that.  Generally speaking, arguments based on the standard are the best and most appropriate ones available, when in fact there are any that apply.  Which in this case there are.

Comment: @LiranFunaro You are confused. See C11 6.6/4. "Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type." Meaning 4x int. And then §11 "The semantic rules for the evaluation of a constant expression are the same as for
nonconstant expressions.". Try it live in GCC: `_Generic(1024*1024*1024*1024, 
    int: printf("it's an int and UB gave value %d", 1024*1024*1024*1024), 
    default: puts("this will never execute"));`. Which will also give you the warning "integer overflow in expression". On my GCC this UB resulted in value 0.

Comment: This answer fails to mention that assigning more than a certain maximum to `malloc` invokes UB, and `malloc` does not have to return a null pointer in this case.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: One does not "assign a certain ammount to `malloc`". You pass how large a block you want and that's it. There is little use to repeat what you can find in any documentation about `malloc`: if something fails, it returns a _null pointer_. **Why** it fails does not matter. Worse: There typically if no specific size which just passes and the next larger failing, but it depends on various factors, including fragmentation. If that's not what you mean, please clarify; as stated, your comment lacks any basis.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: As you don't added this comment to other answers which are even less extensive, there is some bad smell of harrasing or unjustified revenge. A reference to the standard supporting whatever your problem is with the answer would clarify this.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Non sequitur! I'm still waiting for the reference passing a too large value to `malloc` invokes UB! In fact that would break the idea of `malloc` completely. If you pass such a value, `malloc` has to return a null pointer, which I already wrote. Argumentum ad hominem is **not** an argument.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Just in case you don't have the standar at hand: 7.22.3p1 states: "…If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. …" The only exception is "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined" - I don't see `0U` being a too large value. Why the argument in the question can indeed be `0` is clearly handled in my answer. Maybe you read it **carefully** again or ask a colleague of yours.

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions. Your answer will inhibit the question to roomba and cause manual work to the community to delete

Comment: @old_timer: That one is indeed a problem. I should not have VtC, as this is not just a typo problem. We all err sometimes.