# size_t ptrdiff_t and address space

Tags: c++, pointers, size, memory-address

On my system both `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` are ***64-bit***.

I would like to clarify two things:

- I believe that no array could be as large as `size_t` due to address space restrictions. Is this true?
- If yes, then, is there a guarantee that `ptrdiff_t` will be able to hold the result of subtraction of **any** pointers within the max-sized array?

Comment: Not pointers diffrences but result of index subtraction.

Comment: For `ptrdiff_t` to "overflow" , the object size has to be 1 (char sized). For object size > 2 everthing is ok.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I meant was: "pointers to elements of the array".

Comment: What I wanted to bring your attention too,(using @NathanOliver quotes) is that given a definition `long long arr[2]`, then a subtraction `&arr[1] - &arr[0]` gives the result `1` (not `4` as may be expected). So to get this "overflow" problem You have to be dealing with raw memory (1 byte sized types).

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk A remark though. One might expect the result of subtraction from your example to be 8, not 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most implementations artificially restrict the maximum array size to make sure that difference between two pointers pointing into the same array fits into `ptrdiff_t`. So, it is more than likely that on your platform the maximum allowed array size is about `SIZE_MAX / 2` (try it). This is not an "address space restriction", it is just a restriction internally enforced by your implementation. Under this restriction, legal pointer subtraction ("legal" = two pointers into the same array) will not overflow.

The language specification does not require that though. Implementations are not required to restrict their array size in that way, meaning that language specification allows seemingly legal pointer subtractions to overflow and produce undefined behavior. But most implementations prefer to defend against this by restricting their array sizes.

See the "three options" here for more details: [Why is the maximum size of an array "too large"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574890/why-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-too-large/42594384#42594384)

Comment: Indeed! Compiling the following code: `char array[SIZE_MAX/2+1];` results in error: size of array ‘array’ is too large

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such guarantee. See, for example, here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t

> If an array is so large (greater than PTRDIFF_MAX elements, but less
>   than SIZE_MAX bytes), that the difference between two pointers may not
>   be representable as std::ptrdiff_t, the result of subtracting two such
>   pointers is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

From [support.types.layout]/3

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

So you are guaranteed that `size_t` can hold the size of the largest array you can have.

`ptrdiff_t` unfortunately is not so guaranteed.  From [support.types.layout]/2

> The type `ptrdiff_t` is an implementation-defined signed integer type that can hold the difference of two subscripts in an array object, as described in 8.7.

Which is okay-ish but then we have [expr.add]/5

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (21.2). If the expressions P and Q point to, respectively, elements x[i] and x[j] of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i − j; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: If the value i − j is not in the range of representable values of type std::ptrdiff_t, the behavior is undefined. —end note ]

Which states that `ptrdiff_t` may not be large enough.