# How do I use tolower() with a char array?

Tags: c, casting

I'm learning C in school and am doing some input and string comparisons and am running into what looks like a casting issue.

Here is my code:

```c
size_t unit_match_index(char *userInput) {
    char* unit = malloc(strlen(userInput) + 1);
    strcpy(unit, userInput);
    
    //convert to lowercase
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(unit); ++i) {
        unit[i] = tolower(unit[i]);
    /*C6385: invalid data from 'unit': the readable size is 'strlen(userInput)+1' bytes, but 2bytes may be read
      C6386: buffer overrun while writing to 'unit': the writable size is [same as above]
    */
    }
//...
}
```

After doing a little bit of research, it looks like `tolower()` looks for an `int` and returns an `int` (2 bytes), and thinks `strlen(userInput)+1` may equate to `1`, making the total unit array size only 1 byte.

Is there something I should be doing to avoid this, or is this just the analyzer being a computer (computers are dumb)? I'm concerned because I will lose marks on my assignment if there are errors.

Comment: Just use `unit[i] = (char)tolower(unit[i]);`.

Comment: Make sure to `#include <ctype.h>` and cast the argument: `tolower((unsigned char)unit[i])`

Comment: @pmg Even with that cast, the MSVC code analyser still belches. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64713842/10871073) where it seems to have been decided that it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in an answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64713842/10871073), these two warnings are caused by a "bug" in the MSVC Code Analyser.

I even tried the 'fix' I suggested in my answer to that question (that is, using `char* unit = malloc(max(strlen(userInput), 0) + 1);`) – but it didn't work in your code (not sure why).

However, what *did* work (and I have no idea *why*) is to use the `strdup` function in place of your calls to `malloc` and `strcpy` – it does the same thing but in one fell swoop.

Adding the casts (correctly)<sup>1</sup> suggested in the comments, here's a version of your code that doesn't generate the spurious C6385 and C6386 warnings:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t unit_match_index(char* userInput)
{
    char* unit = strdup(userInput);
    //convert to lowercase
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(unit); ++i) {
        unit[i] = (char)tolower((unsigned char)unit[i]);
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

However, MSVC will now generate a *different* (but equally spurious) warning:

> warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated.
> Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online
> help for details.

As it happens, [the `strdup` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) (*without* the leading underscore) is adopted as part of the ISO Standard since C23 (6/2019).

---

<sup>1</sup> On the reasons for the casts when using the `tolower` function, see: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/10871073). However, simply adding those casts **does not** silence the two code analysis warnings.

Comment: That diagnostic can be defeated with a preprocessor definition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility?view=msvc-170.  Microsoft has been issuing brainless warnings about Posix and C standard compatibility for over a decade, while doing nothing to bring their own libraries into compliance with the standards. WinSock is a good/bad example.