# How to create a "X" terminated string in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcmp

I'm trying to create a counter that counts the amount of characters in a string before "?". I have issues with using strcmp to terminate the while-loop and end up with a segmentation fault. Here's what I have:

```
void printAmount(const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ( strcmp(&s[i], "?") != 0 ) {
        i++;
    }
    printf("%i", i);
}
```

Comment: If you want to count characters use character comparison (`s[i] != '?'`). `strcmp` is for comparing null-terminated strings.

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't using `strchr`?

Comment: Your loop should also include some condition for reaching the end of the string without finding a `?` character

Comment: @Lundin Not sure if the OP requires `'\0'` characters inside the string.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Then it isn't a string and strcmp wouldn't work either.

Comment: @Lundin The OP writes that his program ends in a segmentation fault. So we don't know if `strcmp` works. In programming languages that do not use "NUL-terminated strings" (such as Java or C#), `"AB\0C\0D"` is a perfectly valid string containing two NUL bytes in the middle. So why should an `'X'`-terminated string containing NUL bytes not be valid?

Comment: @Lundin Surely you could argue that a string containing NUL bytes in the middle cannot be passed to functions like `puts()`. However, an `'X'`-terminated string cannot be passed to `puts()` anyway so the OP must write his own `strlen()` function (searching for `'X'` instead of `'\0'`) and then use `fwrite()` to write the string to `stdout`. This would also work with an "`'X'`-terminated string" containing NUL bytes in the middle if his `strlen()` implementation treats NUL as normal character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `strcmp` for this. Just use the subscript operator on `s` directly.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAmount(const char *s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '?' && s[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
}

int main() {
    printAmount("Hello?world"); // prints 5
}
```

Or use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)

```
#include <string.h>

void printAmount(const char *s) {
    char *f = strchr(s, '?');
    if (f) {
        printf("%td", f - s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, any particular reason for not using `strchr`?

Comment: @Lundin No, not at all. Added.

Comment: `printf("%zu", f - s);` -> `printf("%td", f - s);`. Or preferably cast to some more sensible type after subtracting the pointers.

Comment: @Lundin Nice. I wasn't even aware `printf` had a special modifier for pointer diffs. Thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Basically its a `size_t`, you get while subtracting two pointers.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is a weird type regardless, so I wouldn't really recommend using it. However, it can actually be larger than `size_t`. `printf("%zu", (size_t)(f - s));` would be fine though.

Comment: @Lundin is the requirement for size_t not `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*)`? There is also `ssize_t` to consider with its own pitfalls (half-range). Don't program in C if you can avoid it :)

Comment: @BitTickler I don't remember the standard giving any such guarantee. However, `sizeof(size_t)` doesn't necessarily correspond to the largest value `SIZE_MAX` of that type. Regarding weird behavior of `size_t` vs `ptrdiff_t` check out this: [Why is the maximum size of an array "too large"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574890/why-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-too-large)

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` compares strings, not characters. So, if you input is something like `"123?456"`, your logic does not work, because `"?" != "?456"`. Thus, your while loop never terminates and you start using stuff outside the string.

```
void printAmount(const char * s) {
  int i = 0;
  for (; s[i] != '?' && s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
     /* empty */
  }
  if (s[i] == '?') {
    printf("%d",i); // the correct formatting string for integer is %d not %i
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very strange or specialized requirements, the correct solution is this:

```
#include <string.h>

char* result = strchr(str, '?');
if(result == NULL) { /* error handling */ }

int characters_before = (int)(result - str);
```