# Struct limit in C

Tags: c

I would like to ask if there is a limit for a struct in C.

I have:

```
#define MAX_DOC_LENGTH (1<<22)
```

And:

```
struct MyDocument {
DocID doc_id;
unsigned int num_res;
QueryID* query_ids;
unsigned int size;
char str[MAX_DOC_LENGTH];
};
```

Comment: Why not just use `char str[];` instead?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are creating an instance of your structure on `heap` or `stack`. If you define a pointer to the object and allocate on the `heap` through `malloc`, then it depends on the available memory of your system.

If you define an instance of the object on the stack as `struct MyDocument mydoc;`, then this is bound to fail as your system will not have such a huge stack value.

It would recommended to declare `str` as a pointer i.e. `char *str` and allocate the memory for the same through `malloc`.

The structure definition could be redefined as

```
struct MyDocument {
    DocID doc_id;
    unsigned int num_res;
    QueryID* query_ids;
    unsigned int size;
    char *str; // Modified the declaration
};
```

With this change, it doesn't matter if you create the object on `stack` or `heap`. If you are defining a `pointer` to the object, then you could allocate the object and `str` as shown in the example below

```
struct MyDocument *myDoc; // Declare an object pointer

myDoc = malloc(sizeof(MyDocument)); // Allocate memory for the object
myDoc->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DOC_LENGTH); // Allocates memory for str
```

Alternatively, you could define an object on the stack and allocate space for `str` only as

```
struct MyDocument someDoc; // Declare an object

someDoc.str = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_DOC_LENGTH); // Allocates memory for str
```

Comment: Can you give me a malloc example as well?

Comment: @Ganesh: Are you aware of a preprocessor macro that stores the maximum size of any object? That is, the maximum value that you may pass to malloc, and the maximum size of any object that may be declared...

Comment: Additionally, I don't think "heap" and "stack" are at all relevant to memory allocation.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Sorry I am unable to recollect. Could you please update? Also, why heap and stack are irrelevant? I am not sure if we can allocate an object that would require say 1 MB on stack. Being from an embedded systems' background, I am not aware if we can really allocate huge objects on stack

Comment: It's quite simple to configure a stack of several gigabytes in Unix.

Comment: @Ganesh Consider an implementation that, upon entrance to a function or block of code, mallocs its non-static locals and upon exit of that block of code, frees them. Are those objects still *on the stack*? If so, does a large object occupy any more space *on the stack* than a small one?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue If you are mallocing the object, it is allocated on the heap. With the original question, `struct MyDocument strDoc;` would create object on the stack. If the object is defined to be in a specific scope, the instantaneous requirement for stack will be higher, even though it is released at the end of the scope. Even though the memory is freed, can a system support such a large request for stack?

Comment: @teppic thank you.. could you please share a reference?

Comment: `ulimit -s 131072` would set the stack to 1gb.

Comment: @Ganesh: I think you've missed my point. Suppose `struct MyDocument strDoc;` creates the object on the heap, instead, and the pointer to that object is stored on the stack. Now, with this in mind, go back and read my last comment and try to respond the same way.

Comment: @Ganesh: A helpful reference is the C standard, which mentions nothing about a stack or heap...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue To quote you _creates the object on the heap, instead, and the pointer to that object is stored on the stack_, yes this is exactly what I have suggested in my response also i.e. define the pointer on stack and allocate on heap

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thanks for your comment. I acknowledge that C Standard doesn't talk about stack or heap, but the implementation is typically environment dependent. Hence, I don't think we can neglect stack and heap. Maybe the perspective is different between PC and embedded worlds. I believe both views are correct and there may not be single solution for both these diverse universes.

Answer (score 1):

Here your problem is associated with the size of the string str not with the number of variables declared inside the structure. There won't be any restrictions by the compiler, if any problem occurs it will be due to the memory capacity.

Comment: There are restrictions by the compiler: A compiler will only support objects up to `SIZE_MAX` bytes in size.

Answer (score 1):

4MB is a probably gonna be too big for the stack. Allocate your `str` on the `heap`.

```
struct MyDocument {
DocID doc_id;
unsigned int num_res;
QueryID* query_ids;
unsigned int size;
char* str;
};
```

And when you allocate:

```
struct MyDocument doc;
doc.str = malloc(MAX_DOC_LENGTH);
```

Comment: It isn't wrong. It's a `char` array. `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: Matt: Indeed, my bad. However, the other discussions may still be interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

`SIZE_MAX`, which is the maximum value of the `size_t` type, is the absolute maximum size (in C's bytes, which have `CHAR_BIT` bits in them, which is >= 8) of any single object in C.

Comment: However, it is not guaranteed that a `struct` can be that large.  See the first answer for a citation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724790/size-limitation-of-c-structure

Comment: @DietrichEpp Funny, that's my own answer. :)